# Trouble Displaying Password as Dots in HTML

Tags: php, html, css

I making a User Registration System and I password to be as dots.

But whenever the page loads, the Email and Password filled in:
Email: root 
Password: password (in dots)

Not happen how?

Comment: sounds like your browser is filling it in. you might try private/incognito mode or deleting saved passwords

Comment: worked. thnx put it up as an answer and i'll accept it. :)

Comment: damn with the downvotes man!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sounds like your browser is filling it in. you might try private/incognito mode or deleting saved passwords